# Where to put a file in the netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

In which location I should put any file in Netbeans project directory structure?
Also in the code how should I give the path(absolute or relative) to that file?

Thanks

Comment: what you are intended to do with that file ?

Comment: Can you please state the OS you are using?

Comment: netbeans is used for several types of projects. Which programming language you are talking about? Also netbeans is an IDE it wont have any problem with your code if it is syntactical correct.

Comment: @ org.life.java any config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about Java,
I would suggest you to put it in `default package` , It would be directly available in classes folder after building, so you can directly access it from classpath.

[Here is sample](http://images.devshed.com/da/stories/SQL_Java_Netbeans2/SampleJavaApp1.zip)